# Can I avoid calling __init__ multiple times in composition of derived class?

Tags: python-2.6, composition

This is a design problem.  I am confused how to use composition in the below problem scenario:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c=None,d=None,e=None,f=None):
      do_something()

    def result():
      #Does some basic processing

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b,e):
      super(B,self).__init__(a,b,e=e)
      self.some_variable = True

    def result(self):
      #Does some advanced processing

class C(A):

    def __init__(self,a,b,c=None,d=None,e=None):
      super(C,self).__init__(a,b,c,=c,d=d,e=e)
      self.b = B(a,b,e=e)
```

The problem with this is that class C creates a class B object as composition but B calls `__init__` for its super class A again.  So I want to avoid calling the constructor of class A again by class C.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to extend C from A, since C is extension of A. And C access the functionality of B via composition.

I dont know python, but of you want i can share Java code that does it.

class C(A):

```
def __init__(self,a,b,c=None,d=None,e=None):
  super(C,self).__init__(a,b,c,=c,d=d,e=e) # assuming it is inheritance.
  self.b = B(a,b,e=e) # assuming it is composition

def result(self):
  self.b.result  #Does some advanced processing
                 # access functionality of B, via object (composition)

def other_functions_2(self):
  self.functionality2 # can access functionality of A, via inheritance
```

Comment: You explained the thing i already told in the question.My question is how do i avoid calling constructor of class A again. In __init__ of class C(A)
1)  super(C,self).__init__(a,b,c,=c,d=d,e=e) calls constructor of class A.
2) In self.b = B(a,b,e=e) as B is calling super(B,self).__init__(a,b,e=e) in its own __init__ so again constructor of class A is called.
I don't want to call "constructor of class A" two times in class C.

Comment: I believe we are dealing with objects, not functions.
Creating/ Calling a constructor of A via C because of inheritance sets things for C object, whereas calling a constructor of A on creating B's object has scope on B's object.

Doing advance processing on B, is via B's object. It is independent of C's object.